# PySpark : regexp_extract

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have in my dataset a column named "description" with a lot of information like this :

| description |
| --- |
| questionA : put returns between paragraphs questionB : indent code by 4 spaces questionC : for linebreak add 2 spaces at end |
| questionA : add language identifier questionB : create code fences questionC : to highlight code |

I want to extract the questionB response with regexp_extract function to obtain this :

| description | regex |
| --- | --- |
| questionA : put returns between paragraphs questionB : indent code by 4 spaces questionC : for linebreak add 2 spaces at end | indent code by 4 spaces |
| questionA : add language identifier questionB : create code fences questionC : to highlight code | create code fences |

How to use `regexp_extract` function to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
df = df.withColumn(
    'regex',
    F.regexp_extract('description', 'questionB : (.+) questionC :', 1)
)
```